# Comma-separated IDREFs XML Schema?

Tags: xml

is it possible to create custom comma-separated IDREFS type. By default in xsd's we have xsd:IDREFS, which allows multiple IDEREF but they are white space-separated. I need a a type which allows comma-separated

Answer (score 0):

You could define a subtype of xs:string that holds something like this using a pattern facet something like

```
((\i\c+),\s*)*(\i\c+)
```

But of course it wouldn't have the "referential" semantics of the IDREFS type.